# Unable to register the service worker

Tags: ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, ionic4

My app is under ionic 4 angular.
I've installed the pwa part with :

```
ng add @angular/pwa --project app
```

Then I build with : `ionic build --prod`

and deployed to firebase with : `firebase deploy`

But I have 2 problems :

1) the banner "add to screen" is not shown when I browse the app from my android phone.
Even with this code on the root url :

```
showBtn: boolean = false;
  deferredPrompt;
  constructor(private modalController: ModalController, public authUser: AuthUserService, private router: Router){}

  ionViewWillEnter(){
    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
      // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
      e.preventDefault();
      // Stash the event so it can be triggered later on the button event.
      this.deferredPrompt = e;

    // Update UI by showing a button to notify the user they can add to home screen
      this.showBtn = true;
    });

    //button click event to show the promt

    window.addEventListener('appinstalled', (event) => {
     alert('installed');
    });


    if (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches) {
      alert('display-mode is standalone');
    }
  }
```

2) When I launch lighthouse audit I get this warning :

```
Does not register a service worker that controls page and start_url
```

I've tried to uninstall, reinstall, rebuild everything but nothing works.
On ionic docs I can't find any clue to fix this problem.

Answer (score 4):

After many days I was able to make it works.

First I add this following snippet to the firebase.json file to the hosting property:

```
{
        "source": "ngsw-worker.js",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache"
          }
        ]
      }
```

Then I add this script in my index.html :

```
<script>
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('ngsw-worker.js')
      .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
      .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
  }
</script>
```

Now it works !